# from google.cloud import storage fails: ImportError: No module named google.cloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I'm having issue with accessing Google Storage through Python 3.6.I'm installing with:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

Here's my Python script:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def main():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
    blob1 = bucket.blob('my_file.json')
    blob1.upload_from_filename(filename='my_file.json')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`pip show google-cloud-storage` gives me following output:

```
Name: google-cloud-storage
Version: 1.6.0
Summary: Python Client for Google Cloud Storage
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: google-api-core, google-auth, google-cloud-core, requests, google-resumable-media
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have Google Cloud Python Client installed? `$ pip install --upgrade google-cloud`

Comment: Yes it’s installed

Answer (score 3):

There is a chance you are installing it with one `python` version (E.g. `python2`) and running your code with another version (E.g. `python3`).

Try mentioning versions of `pip` and `python` in the command.

To be precise, use pip of the python version you wanna run the code with. Example:

```sh
python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

There could be multiple versions of Python installed on your system and multiple versions of `pip` as well, the above will make sure you are using the correct version of **both**.

Comment: Usually running this with python3 and pip3 install might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved by running my script as administrator.